# Symplectic submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Which symplectic submanifolds can be realized in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with standard ($\text{d}\,\boldsymbol{p} \wedge \text{d}\,\boldsymbol{q}$) symplectic structure? It's easy to show that such submanifolds aren't compact. So, they are spheres with some handles and holes. Which relations between the numbers of holes and handles do exist?

Comment: Every algebraic curve in the complex projective plane, minus the points that lie on a complex projective line. So that gives any compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ minus a set of $d$ points so that $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$.

Comment: Moreover you may allow your curve to be singular at infinity, and/or the infinity line to have multiple contact with the curve. This should give any $g$ and $d$ provided $g$ is not too large w.r.t. $d$.

Comment: If you keep track of the complex structure on an algebraic curve, not every set of $d$ points can be removed from a curve of genus $g$ by slicing with a projective line in an embedding in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. But symplectically, by Moser's lemma, you can move any discrete set of distinct points around anywhere, as you like.

Comment: In fact, you can get any genus minus a single point:  Just take a hyperelliptic curve $z^2 = P(w)$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $2g+1$ with no repeated roots.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. The level of holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is lagrangian, not symplectic.

Comment: The level sets of a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ are symplectic when the symplectic form is the Kaehler form. The holomorphic curves on any Kaehler manifold are symplectic in the Kaehler form.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It looks like that I should reformulate my question: which symplectic submanifolds can be realized in $(\mathbb{R}^4(p_1, q_1, p_2,  q_2), \omega^2)$? Here $\omega = \text{d}\,\boldsymbol{p} \wedge \text{d}\,\boldsymbol{q}$.

Comment: The  standard Kähler form of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is of that form.

Comment: Yea? So, it is not true that for every function $F = f_1 + i f_2$ the Poisson bracket $\left\{ f_1, f_2 \right\} = 0$ if and only if $F$ is holomorphic?

Comment: Certainly not, take $f_1=f_2$.

Comment: Of course, they should be independent.

Comment: Even with the independence assumption, just look in two dimensions:  The standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$ is $dx\wedge dy$ and the function $z = x + iy$ is holomorphic, but $\{x,y\}\not=0$.

Comment: But the level $z = \text{const}$ is just a point and that's why it's isotropic. So, I mean $\left\{f_1, f_2\right\}|_{\text{level F}} = 0$. This effect exists only in dimension 4.

Comment: Just add a dimension:  If you take the complex structure for which $z = p_1 + i q_1$ and $w = p_2 + i q_2$ are holomorphic coordinates, then $F = z= p_1 + i q_1$ is holomorphic, but $\{p_1,q_1\}\not=0$, when $\omega = dp_1\wedge dq_1 +dp_2\wedge dq_2 $.